# How to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML on input tag of type checkbox in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

I have multiple checkboxes and the checkbox label are html string. When rendering, the html string are getting printed as it is, the tags are not rendering. I tried using "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" on my input element but it is throwing an error as "input is a void element tag and must neither have 'children' nor use 'dangerouslySetInnerHTML'.

Here is the code:

```
import { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const MyCheckBoxList = [
  {
    order: 0,
    name: "<p>This is some label. <ul><li>Something else</li></ul></p>"
  },
  {
    order: 1,
    name: "<p>Some checkbox value. <ul><li>Something else</li></ul></p>"
  },      
];

const Checkbox = ({ obj, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id={`custom-checkbox-${obj.index}`}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML ={{__html:obj.name}}
        value={obj.checked}
        onChange={() => onChange({ ...obj, checked: !obj.checked })}
      />
      {obj.name}
    </>
  );
};
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(
    MyCheckBoxList.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order)
  );

  const isVerified = useMemo(() => {
    return data.every((d) => d.checked);
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map((obj, index) => (
        <li key={index}>
          <Checkbox
            obj={obj}
            onChange={(item) => {
              setData(data.map((d) => (d.order === item.order ? item : d)));
            }}
          />
        </li>
      ))}
      <button disabled={!isVerified}>Final button</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Can anybody help me on this? Thank You

Comment: `input` tags don't have innerHTML or any children at all.

Comment: Can you please suggest what should I change in the code to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with react or jsx, but if you're trying to update a label, you'd have to do so on the label itself, which I'm not seeing here.